# Why can't I use the overloaded == that takes two structs when the values used are implicitly convertable to these structs?

Tags: c#, struct, implicit-conversion

I've noticed a difference between the behavior of user-defined implicit conversion to `int` and user-defined implicit conversion to an arbitrary struct `MyStruct` when applying `operator==`.

If I have:

```
public struct IntA
{
    public IntA(int value)
    { m_value = value; }

    public static implicit operator int(IntA a)
    { return a.m_value; }

    private int m_value;
}

public struct IntB
{
    public IntB(int value)
    { m_value = value; }

    public static implicit operator int(IntB b)
    { return b.m_value; }

    private int m_value;
}
```

Then the following code compiles:

```
{
    var a = new IntA(3);
    var b = new IntB(4);

    bool equal = (a == b); // ok! converted to int and used int operator==

    // ...
}
```

This uses my user-defined `implicit operator int` for `IntA` and `IntB` to convert to `int`, then invoke `operator==(int, int)`.

However, if I have:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStruct(int value)
    { m_value = value; }

    public static bool operator==(MyStruct lhs, MyStruct rhs)
    { return lhs.m_value == rhs.m_value; }

    public static bool operator!=(MyStruct lhs, MyStruct rhs)
    { return lhs.m_value != rhs.m_value; }

    private int m_value;
}

public struct MyStructA
{
    public MyStructA(int value)
    { m_value = new MyStruct(value); }

    public static implicit operator MyStruct(MyStructA a)
    { return a.m_value; }

    private MyStruct m_value;
}

public struct MyStructB
{
    public MyStructB(int value)
    { m_value = new MyStruct(value); }

    public static implicit operator MyStruct(MyStructB b)
    { return b.m_value; }

    private MyStruct m_value;
}
```

Then the following code does *not* compile:

```
{
    var a = new MyStructA(3);
    var b = new MyStructB(4);

    bool equal = (a == b); // compile error: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `MyStructA' and `MyStructB'
                           // why can't it convert to MyStruct and use that operator==?

    // ...
}
```

I expected it to do the same as the previous example, and use my user-defined `implicit operator MyStruct` to convert to `MyStruct`, then invoke `operator==(MyStruct, MyStruct)`.

It doesn't do that. Why not? What's the different between these two cases from the compiler's perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the language spec.  Emphasis is mine.

> ### C# Language Specification 7.3.4
>
> An operation of the form x op y, where op is an overloadable binary
>   operator, x is an expression of type X, and y is an expression of type
>   Y, is processed as follows:
>
> - The set of candidate user-defined operators provided by X and Y for    the operation operator op(x, y) is determined. The set consists of 
>     the union of the candidate operators provided by X and the candidate 
>     operators provided by Y, each determined using the rules of §7.3.5. 
>     If X and Y are the same type, or if X and Y are derived from a common 
>     base type, then shared candidate operators only occur in the combined 
>     set once.
> - If the set of candidate user-defined operators is not empty, then    this becomes the set of candidate operators for the operation.  ***Otherwise, the predefined binary operator op implementations,    including their lifted forms,  become the set of candidate operators
>
>     for the operation***. The predefined implementations of a given
>     operator    are specified in the description of the operator (§7.8
>     through    §7.12). For predefined enum and delegate operators, the
>     only    operators considered are those defined by an enum or delegate
>     type    that is the binding-time type of one of the operands.
> - The overload resolution rules of §7.5.3 are applied to the set of candidate operators to select the best operator with respect to the 
>     argument list (x, y), and this operator becomes the result of the 
>     overload resolution process. If overload resolution fails to select a 
>     single best operator, a binding-time error occurs.

So, if there's no initial match, it considers all the internally defined `==` operators as candidates.  And since there is one for `int`, but not `MyStruct`, you see different behavior.